# "Hello world" as a Gmail plugin?

Tags: gmail

I am trying to find out what the tech is like to create a Gmail plugin that accesses my attachments. Just to get started, what would be "Hello world" as a Gmail plugin? What would be the steps to create it?

Comment: May I suggest a plugin for Chrome or another browser that supports extensions instead?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can creates plugin for Gmail, and two types:

- Sidebar
- Contextual

Look for Gadgets in gmail. After learning how to use these, you can add them to your gmail or anybody that wants to can do the same, to do so you can have Google host it.

It's easy if you know some `HTML`, `JavaScript`, and `XML`.

Good Luck

Take a look at these links:

- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets
- https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/basic

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create Gmail plugins.
(Unless you work for Google)

Comment: So how do companies like rapportive.com or mailbrowser.com make this work? Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology and it isn't called a "plugin".

Comment: @user They are browser extensions for Safari, Firefox, and Chrome (each of which has its own extension API).

Comment: Really? Thanks! That does sound like a lot of work. Are there any libraries/etc around that would make that more easy, perhaps abstract those APIs, or do you have to write an extension for each? Sounds like it :)

Comment: For a start, you may use ChickenFoot, it has a quite good DOM parser/XPath search, is able to create .xpi extensions out of the box. You should do it yourself though... just write your code as .js (Firefox is JS mostly), make xpi.

Answer (score 2):

Doing some quick research it looks like Google now supports a GMail api to build gadgets and/or plugins. I haven't done it myself, however it seems like they want it to work.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that. (You will find Hello World program too)
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/gadgets/contextual/

Answer (score 1):

Last year, Google released a GMail API and it allows you to perform the actions you want, but perhaps not with the UX you're looking for embedded directly inside of GMail. You can find it here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Depending on exactly how you need it to work, you might be able to use either Contextual Gadgets (https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets) or a Google Chrome Extension to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Google has recently introduced add-ons for Gmail (probably on Oct, 24 2017). It can be developed with Google Apps Script. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) says

**What Gmail add-ons can do ?**

> Displaying additional information for the user in the Gmail UI.
>   Connecting to non-Google services, to retrieve information or take other actions.
>   Providing an interactive interface to allow the user to control the add-on or send information to another service.

I am not pretty sure (will go deep into it in coming days) whether you can deal with attachments. But I logically feel you can do that as well, because [GAS supports handling attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment).

As of now, Google [is not allowing](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish) to publish new add-ons however they will allow it in future.

> While a few add-ons have been made available in the G Suite
>   Marketplace for users to install, it is not currently possible to
>   publish your own add-on to the Marketplace.

**How can you publish your own add-on ?**

As of now (26th Oct, 2017), they consider it on request basis. If you have a cool idea, [fill this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdQD9F5TXZvlpQcY1I6fvaZqLvULG1THhou3y5IpRRwjgwZYg/viewform) to let them know about it. You will get notified once they accept your listing.

**Here is how the add-on interface looks like inside Gmail**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create plugins for Gmail. There is no developer API as such - only access to send/retrieve emails using standard SMTP/IMAP protocols.

See http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/

Comment: GMail had a limited subset of Greasemonkey API via JS in-page.. Hey, don't you know, does OAuth over HTTP allows me to get a full list of messages in inbox?

Comment: @William the Google team must have read your comment because a Gmail API now does exist.